# How to load required packages of a custom package silently

Tags: r, r-package

I have added a `zzz.R` file in the `R` directory of my package, with `.onLoad` and `.onAttach`, but I can't figure out how to silently load the required packages listed on the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Part of the `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Depends: mclust
```

If I load my package, the startup message of `mclust` shows up.

```
library("mypackage")
Loading required package: mclust
    __  ___________    __  _____________
   /  |/  / ____/ /   / / / / ___/_  __/
  / /|_/ / /   / /   / / / /\__ \ / /   
 / /  / / /___/ /___/ /_/ /___/ // /    
/_/  /_/\____/_____/\____//____//_/    version 5.4
Type 'citation("mclust")' for citing this R package in publications.
```

Comment: Question ambiguous, be more specific.

Comment: I edited my question to add more specific info.

Comment: If you are doing this in a markdown file you can put `message=F` in the chunk options, otherwise put your package inside the `suppressMessages()` function.

Comment: It is not a markdown file, so, you mean that I should use, `suppressMessages()` when I load my package or inside the `.onLoad` or `.onAttach` function? I want the messages of other packages to not show up when the end-user uses, `library("mypackage")`.

Comment: `suppressMessages(library("mypackage"))`

Comment: Thanks, I knew about this, but I was trying to find out if there is any way to let the user use, `library("mypackage")` and have no other startup messages show up.

Comment: Is there a reason why you must depend on `mclust`? Recommended practice is to `Import` and `importFrom` what you need instead of `Depend`. If you follow that practice, there should be no startup message because `mclust` would not be attached.